# Git - master working copy the same as clone working copy

Tags: git

I've made lots of changes on a cloned git repository. Now I want the master to look exactly like the cloned copy - what command do I need to execute to that the master syncs with the clone?

**Duplicate of:** [Git - pulling changes from clone back onto the master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286988/git-pulling-changes-from-clone-back-onto-the-master)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you cloned the repository with:

```
git clone >>wherever<<
```

you push it back (from the copy) with:

```
git push origin master
```

Note that *master* stands for master branch of your repository and *origin* is automatically created reference to the original repository.