# New to git -- how do I get changes from cloned repo into original repo?

Tags: git, version-control

This is probably quite a newb question, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here's what I did...

On the server (via ssh):

- Created a site on a dedicated server
- Created a git repo there (`git init` I think?)
- Added and committed everything

At my office:

- Cloned the repo on my development machine
- Pulled everything
- Made some changes to local files
- Added the files again (is this right? not like svn!)
- Did a commit
- Did a push

...now, on the server, if I do `git show`, it shows a diff where the server's last copy of stuff is removed and the stuff I pushed from my office is being added. That's what I want to happen. What I can't figure out is: **what do I need to do on the server to make the changes I pushed from my office become "live?"**

I've had pretty good success deploying websites with svn in the past, and I figure I can get away with it with git too... but obviously I'm missing some piece of the puzzle. Thanks for any help.

---

**edit** - I just noticed this post: [Git - pulling changes from clone back onto the master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286988/git-pulling-changes-from-clone-back-onto-the-master)

Should I be pulling my office repo onto my server instead of pusing it there? So ssh from the office into the server and then have it git+ssh back into the office to pull that repo? That seems kind of crazy, I'd rather figure out how to make the push go through if possible.

---

**rephrasing the question**

I really just want to apply the patch shown by `git show`. Does git have a built-in way of doing that?

---

**answer**

It looks like `git checkout -f` on the server did what I wanted, but creating a --bare repo would have been a better way to go (I've changed to this setup now).

Comment: People really need to learn the difference between comments and answers.  You could probably get rep for this...  :)

Comment: Your question is very similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298499/git-push-not-send-changes-to-remote-git-repository :: Generally you only want to push into a bare repository

Comment: @cHao: Well... I realized this myself already... deleted comment. I tend to comment rather than answer if my answer is somewhat incomplete.

Comment: See my edited answer. `git reset` is probably what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually on the server you would do a `git init --bare` which creates a repo with no working directory.  If that is the route you took then you would have to pull the changes from there to the web directory as the "deployment" step.  So your work flow might look like...

```
On dev PC:

1. git clone <path to server repo>

*make code changes*

2. git commit -am "fixed a bug"

*add some new feature*

3. git commit -am "added cool new feature"

4. git push origin master


On the server:

*cd to www folder*

5. git pull
```

1. Clones server repo to your dev machine, which you've already done
2. Commits the bug fix to your **local** repo...not the server's repo
3. Commits the new feature to your **local** repo...again, not the server's
4. Pushes all changes from your master branch to the server's master branch

At this point, none of your changes are visible on your website.  You would need to "deploy" them.

5.Pulls the latest changes from the central repo on the server to the web server's folder(s) that are being served up on the web.

There [git tutorials](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gittutorial.html) are very good as is "[Pro Git](http://progit.org/book/)", a free online book

Comment: Okay, I'll try this... what steps should I take to set up my 'bare' repo and check everything into it given the position I'm in now? I don't really care about these recent changes, they are small and I can always patch them in later.

Comment: http://progit.org/book/ch4-4.html  ... search for "git --bare init".  The stuff above that is for user setup which I presume you've already done.

Comment: I'm committing my clone into a bare repo on the server now. Did a `git remote origin (bare repo)`. Should I be able to (re)move the .git folder on the original non-bare repo, then give it a remote to the new (bare, but with my stuff checked in from clone) repo, and then update to sync everything?

Comment: Heh, look at this: `git checkout`
warning: You appear to be on a branch yet to be born.
warning: Forcing checkout of HEAD.
fatal: just how do you expect me to merge 0 trees?

Comment: @no, irc://irc.freenode.net/git ... the git IRC channel is a great resource for live troubleshooting help.

Answer (score 1):

If the git repo on the server you pushed to is for the live system, you would probably have to do a [**EDIT**] `git reset [--hard|...] HEAD` on the server after a push I guess (see [git-reset man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) for details on whether using `--hard` or something else; `--hard` **resets all** non-committed modifications on your server).

If the live system is somewhere else on the server, do a `git pull` from your repo you pushed to (in the directory with your live system).

*push* and *fetch* are complementary, i.e. pushing from A to B is like fetching A from B.
*pull* is a *fetch* followed by a *checkout*.

**EDIT:**
You should also read the article linked to by [jmohr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16548/jmohr) on the subtle differences between *push* and *fetch* / *pull*: [git push not send changes to remote git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298499/git-push-not-send-changes-to-remote-git-repository)

Comment: `git checkout (something)` or just `git checkout`? `git checkout` shows M (modified?) and a bunch of files, but the changes don't appear and `git show` gives the same output afterwards... weird.  +1 for "push and fetch are complementary."

Comment: `git checkout -f` ("proceed even if the index or working tree is not HEAD") made the changes to the live files, but `git info` still shows the same diff... this bothers me. Should I do a `git clean` or something?

Comment: Sorry, just updated my answer. It should be `git reset`, but still, pushing to a non-bare repository is not very good practice as it seems. Better have a bare repo and pull from there to your live system.

Comment: The git-reset didn't seem to do anything useful as far as cleaning up `git show`, but I probably should have done it before I tried `git checkout -f`... hmm, I'll see what I can do about a bare repo

Comment: Doing a `git reset --hard HEAD` in the (non-bare) repository you pushed to should update your working copy files to the most recent pushed commit.

Comment: It may have done that if I hadn't already done `git checkout -f`, which did do that. The problem I have now is `git show` still shows a diff with those changes when it should probably not. I'll update my question.

Comment: Running `git show` in your working copy just displays your last commit. The changes have been applied already.

Comment: Heheh, yeah I was just realizing that. I marked @dgnorton's answer as correct; I guess --bare was the way to go, but  `git checkout -f` and a non-bare repo probably would have worked. Best to do things the Right Way(TM), though.